# Decreasing time interval between two consecutive double click event in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i decrease time interval between two consecutive double click jquery event.
Currently i need to wait around 2 sec to execute a proper next double click. Is there a way to remove that 2 sec time interval and make it less?

Like you can even see on jquery api website : http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/
Continous double click is not working, but if you wait 2 sec and double click, then demo works.

Comment: I think its the windows/OS double click setting.

Comment: Continuous double click works for me. Windows 8 + Firefox. If the double click settings are system dependent, then to be able to handle settings yourself you might have to write your own double click handler?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue on win7 and ubuntu